# The private static function cannot use the paramater, because of the paramater is used in while loop so, how to fix this problem?

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, boolean

I am making a program to find a weekday with basic method so, the program gets input the weekday of 1 January in entered year after that the program will check the input is true or false according to weekDays array if it is true program will continue if it is false, the program will gets re-input so, it is working correctly but It occurs a problem.

Actually, I have to use the string outside of the while loop becuase I will use this string in my other function or what else

```java
boolean bool1 = false;
        while (!bool1){
            System.out.print("Enter weekday of 1 January (Monday, Tuesday, ...): ");
            String firstJanuary = scan2.nextLine();
            if (!firstJanuary.equals("")) {
                if (contains(weekdays, firstJanuary)) {
                    bool1 = true;
                }
            }
        }

private static String findWeekday(int year, int month, int day, String firstJanuary) {
```

I expect the program use the `firstJanuary` as a parameter so, I see that the `firstJanuary` used in while loop because of this, the program occurs a error. so, How can I re-write the same logical while loop?

Comment: take it outside the loop. String firstJanuary. and your loop is running forever why ?

Comment: If I undertand well you want to do the same loop but check if the value of firstJuanary is set and if it is correct before rewrite it with you scan?

Comment: Something like that, I want to use the firstJanuary as a paramater in function but I cannot do that exactly

Comment: And you dont enter the loop if the value is correct that it?

Comment: We have to re-write to while loop with using the `firstJanuary` outside of the loop to use in function.

Comment: Please post the complete code you have wrote

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this :

```
public youFunction(String firstJanuary) {
   while (firstJanuary.equals("") || !contains(weekdays, firstJanuary)){
      System.out.print("Enter weekday of 1 January (Monday, Tuesday, ...): ");
      firstJanuary = scan2.nextLine();
   }
}
```

Comment: Send the complet function. this part of ode alone sould work